# c# accessor not called by reference

Tags: c#, properties, reference, inotifypropertychanged

my problem is the following. I Have a class with a peoperty:

```
public partial class GraphView : UserControl
{
    private ObservableChartDictionary _dictionary;
    public ObservableChartDictionary dictionary
    {
        get
        {
            return _dictionary;
        }
        set
        {
            this._dictionary = value;
            this.signals = ChartConverter(value);

        }
     }
 }
```

I make this property later equal to an other object.

```
 myGraphView.dictionary = this.dictionary;
```

When I do this, the setter of my property runs nicely through. This means also

```
 this.signals = ChartConverter(value);
```

is executed. If I change the referenced object, "this.dictionary" the value appears in "myGraphView.dictionary", but the setter doesn't execute, and my conversion doesn't happens.

How should I solve this? My class ObservableChartDictionary also implement INotifyPropertyChanged, but the event is not raised in "myGraphView.dictionary" either. Please help!

Comment: Changing something within the dictionary is not `set`ting the property of the class. If you need to know when the dictionary changes (as well as when you change dictionaries), then you cannot do that with a simple property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because you are changing the dictionary some way like

```
this.dictionary.someproperty ... or this.dictionary.someMethod(...)
```

this way the setter property will not fire. It just changes the content of your dictionary and the other reference to it sees the changes.

this.dictionary = something fires the set property.

If you want to detect changes this code may helps :

```
    public class ObservableChartDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public TValue this[TKey key]
        {
            get { return this[key]; }
            set
            {
                base[key]= value;
                OnPropertyChanged(key.ToString());
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that is the cause. But how can I force the myGraphView.dictionary to recognise the change? I tried with INotifyPopertyChanged but the event doesnt fire in myGraphView.Dictionary. Why is that?

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Turns out the mistake I was still making, is signing up for the Porpertychanged event before assigning the reference to my property. This deleted my subscription!

Answer (score 0):

The observableDictionary is only made for the graphView, right? If you want to connect them, why don`t you just link your ObservableChartDictionary instance to an actual graph view..

```
public class ObservableChartDictionary
{
    public GraphView linkedGraph { get; set; }

    public ObservableChartDictionary(GraphView linkedGraph)
    {
        this.linkedGraph = linkedGraph;
    }

    //...      
}
```

then you can update the value from the dictionary itself whenever the dictionary changes (I property notification changed for example):

```
        if (linkedGraph != null)
        {
             linkedGraph .signals = ChartConverter(this);
        }
```

So it will update the graph everytime you add an entry or change something.

you can even make a nested class to show they are tightly connected.